# How add special char into string

Tags: c#

I have a string 7889875487 I want to change this string into (788)-987-5487. I was trying with taking sub string but not getting success.

```
var mainStr = string.Empty;
var str1 = string.Empty;
var str2 = string.Empty;
var str3 = string.Empty;

 str1 = item.PrimaryPhoneNumber.ToString().Substring(0,3);
 str2 = item.PrimaryPhoneNumber.ToString().Substring(3, 5);
 str3 = item.PrimaryPhoneNumber.ToString().Substring(5);

 mainStr = "(" + str1 + ")" + "-" + str2 + "-" + str3;
```

someone please help me with better solution.

Comment: what result are you getting?

Comment: use `string.Format` instead of `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
string item = "7889875487";
string str1 = item.Substring(0, 3);
string str2 = item.Substring(3, 3);
string str3 = item.Substring(6);

string mainStr = "(" + str1 + ")" + "-" + str2 + "-" + str3;
```

the 2nd parameter of `String.Substring(3, 5)` is the length, not the 2nd index

Comment: C# 6 please
`string mainStr = $"({item.Substring(0, 3)})-{item.Substring(3, 3)}-{item.Substring(6)}";`

Answer (score 3):

Something like that:

```
  String phone = item.PrimaryPhoneNumber.ToString();

  mainStr = String.Format("({0})-{1}-{2}",
    phone.SubString(0, 3), // starting from 0th, 3 characters length
    phone.SubString(3, 3), // starting from 3d, 3 characters length
    phone.SubString(6));   // starting from 6th, up to the end
```

note, that the second argument in `SubString` is *length*, not *position*.

Answer (score 0):

You may look for a regex solution.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private string phoneFormating(string unformatedString)
{
    Regex phone_reg = new Regex(@"^(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)$");//you could write it like this too: (@"^(\d){3}(\d){3}(\d){4}$")
    Match m = phone_reg.Match(unformatedString);
    if (m.Success)//ie if your input string is 10 numbers only
    {
        string formatedString = "(" + m.Groups[1].Value + ")-" + m.Groups[2].Value + "-" + m.Groups[3].Value;
            return formatedString;
    }
    else {return string.Empty;}//or anything else.
}
```

then your code is:

```
string result = phoneFormating(mainStr);
```